# Why was my ceph specific question marked as a duplicate of a generalized question by multiple users?

Tags: discussion

I honestly cant understand how and why, it made me very angry.

[How much RAM and CPU cores would you recommend when using ceph only as block storage for KVM?](https://serverfault.com/questions/925186)

Those who marked it as a duplicate obvious didnt read the tag/topic or dont know what ceph is and shouldve ignored the question.

Do people get rewards for marking questions as duplicate?

Answer (score 8):

Obviously you were so angry that you didn't even read the duplicate target question.

We don't allow this type of capacity planning questions and the "duplicate target" is meant to explain why we don't. It doesn't matter at all if this is about Ceph or web servers, databases or whatever. We can't really help in the context of our site.

That said: Frankly, your original question is terrible and a prime example why we don't allow this. With what you explained, it's impossible to come up with a suggestion.

Comment: take me asking a SeaweedFS specific question for example, someone who has it in production made server recommendations based on the fact that we have the same use case https://github.com/chrislusf/seaweedfs/issues/425 I was expecting the same here, someone actually made a valid answer relating to using ceph with RC and it made sense

Comment: "1GB  RAM per TB storage recommendation still stands as far as I know plus you want some for the OS and some safety margin so in your case 64GB seem sensible" is what I got from the ceph community, the answer I was looking for.

Comment: in the description I have "The case is 28TB", I'm still lost to how is the question a duplicate

Comment: We don't accept capacity planning questions. If your question is "I have resource X - is this enough to do Y" or "How much of X do I need to do Y" then it's not welcome here. The reason is is that in 99% of cases there is no simple rule and you have to test for your specific workload. It might be that this isn't true for Ceph and there is an easy formula to follow, but even then I guess it's just a rule of thumb and  the full answer is more complex with a lot of "it depends".